# I just created this trigger in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

here is the code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tupdate_hist_station
AFTER INSERT ON STATION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    V_num_station STATION.NUM_STATION%type;
    V_nb_reserve CLIENTS.NB_RESERV%type;
    V_revenue number;

    BEGIN

    SELECT s.NUM_STATION INTO v_num_station
    FROM STATION s
    WHERE s.NUM_STATION =: NEW.NUM_STATION;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("There is no new data added");
    END;

    BEGIN

    SELECT sum(c.NB_RESERV) INTO V_nb_reserve 
    FROM CLIENTS c, RESERVATION r, CHAMBRE ch, HOTEL h, STATION s
    WHERE c.NUMC = r.NUMC AND r.IDCHAMBRE = ch.IDCHAMBRE AND ch.NUM_HOTEL = h.NUM_HOTEL
    AND h.NUM_STATION = s.NUM_STATION AND s.NUM_STATION = v_num_station;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN V_nb_reserve:=0;    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line("There is no reservation in a hotel in this station yet");
    END;

    BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(p.MONTANT) INTO V_revenue 
    FROM PAYEMENT p, CLIENTS c, RESERVATION r, CHAMBRE ch, HOTEL h, STATION s
    where p.NUMC = c.NUMC 
    AND c.NUMC = r.NUMC
    AND r.IDCHAMBRE = ch.IDCHAMBRE
    AND ch.NUM_HOTEL = h.NUM_HOTEL
    and h.NUM_STATION = s.NUM_STATION AND s.NUM_STATION = v_num_station;    

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    V_revenue := 0;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line("There is no reservation in this station yet");    
    END;

    INSERT INTO HIST_STATION("NUM_STATION","ANNEE","NB_RESERV","REVENU") VALUES (V_num_station,(SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY')FROM DUAL),V_nb_reserve,V_revenue);

END;

SHOW ERRORS;
```

when i insert values in station table i get these error:

> INSERT INTO "DANIEL"."STATION" (NUM_STATION, NOM_STATION, ALTITUDE, REGION) VALUES ('6', 'Baalbak', '1250', 'Baalbak')
>
> ORA-04098: trigger 'DANIEL.TUPDATE_HIST_STATION' is invalid and failed re-validation
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> One error saving changes to table "DANIEL"."STATION":
>
> Row 6: ORA-04098: trigger 'DANIEL.TUPDATE_HIST_STATION' is invalid and failed re-validation
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

instead of inserting a new row in Hist_station

Comment: Your trigger was not properly compiled at first, hence it fails to execute. Check for compilation erros : `select * from user_errors  where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'TUPDATE_HIST_STATION';`

Comment: What dd the `show errors` say? If it ran, that is - do you have a slash (`/`) after the `end;`? The block structure looks off though, you might want to review that. You may just want another `begin` before the first one you have now, but it would still look a bit odd.

Comment: "`s.NUM_STATION =: NEW.NUM_STATION`" -- that colon seems to be stray and wants to go back to `NEW`. It also seems like you miss one `BEGIN`, the very first one as the others seem to belong to the sub blocks. It would be easier to spot if you used indentation for the sub blocks.

Comment: If the tool you are using for development does not clearly highlight compilation errors then you should consider switching to a different tool.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, there are various errors. The biggest problem, though, is that the code that inserts data into HIST_STATION is not part of the trigger - it's just wandering around out in space somewhere.

When I started adjusting the indentation of your code to figure out what was going on, here's what I got:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tupdate_hist_station
  AFTER INSERT ON STATION
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_num_station STATION.NUM_STATION%type;
  V_nb_reserve  CLIENTS.NB_RESERV%type;
  V_revenue     number;
BEGIN
    SELECT s.NUM_STATION
      INTO v_num_station
      FROM STATION s
      WHERE s.NUM_STATION =: NEW.NUM_STATION;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("There is no new data added");
END;
```

Your trigger ends, right there, after the first `END`. All the other code is just...gone.

I think that what you wanted was:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tupdate_hist_station
  AFTER INSERT ON STATION
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_num_station STATION.NUM_STATION%type;
  V_nb_reserve  CLIENTS.NB_RESERV%type;
  V_revenue     number;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT s.NUM_STATION
      INTO v_num_station
      FROM STATION s
      WHERE s.NUM_STATION = :NEW.NUM_STATION;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("There is no new data added");
  END;

  BEGIN
    SELECT sum(c.NB_RESERV)
      INTO V_nb_reserve 
      FROM CLIENTS c,
           RESERVATION r,
           CHAMBRE ch,
           HOTEL h,
           STATION s
      WHERE c.NUMC = r.NUMC AND
            r.IDCHAMBRE = ch.IDCHAMBRE AND
            ch.NUM_HOTEL = h.NUM_HOTEL AND
            h.NUM_STATION = s.NUM_STATION AND
            s.NUM_STATION = v_num_station;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      V_nb_reserve:=0;    
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line("There is no reservation in a hotel in this station yet");
  END;

  BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(p.MONTANT) INTO V_revenue 
      FROM PAYEMENT p,
           CLIENTS c,
           RESERVATION r,
           CHAMBRE ch,
           HOTEL h,
           STATION s
      where p.NUMC = c.NUMC AND
            c.NUMC = r.NUMC AND
            r.IDCHAMBRE = ch.IDCHAMBRE AND
            ch.NUM_HOTEL = h.NUM_HOTEL and
            h.NUM_STATION = s.NUM_STATION AND
            s.NUM_STATION = v_num_station;    
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      V_revenue := 0;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line("There is no reservation in this station yet");    
  END;

  INSERT INTO HIST_STATION
    ("NUM_STATION","ANNEE","NB_RESERV","REVENU")
  VALUES
    (V_num_station,(SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY')FROM DUAL),V_nb_reserve,V_revenue);
END tupdate_hist_station;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
/
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Good job Bob. This is another example of the importance of proper layout. It's not just mindless standards adherence, it's a useful diagnostic tool. Readability is a feature.

Comment: To quote [Abelson and Sussman in "The Structure And Interpretation Of Computer Programs"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html), ""Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute". I recently had to modify some code at work that everyone (*perhaps* barring the original author, now long departed and little lamented) who ever looked at it complained bitterly about. The output of `diff` now looks like the output of `cat` but, by Perlis, no one will ever complain about how hard it is to figure out again! :-)